# DB2 accent insensitive UPPERCASE JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, db2, openjpa

Is there any way of getting Uppercase accent insensitive in DB2 but using Java JPA? I need something like:

```sql
select translate(upper('dénes'),'ÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÃÕÂÊÎÔÛÄËÏÖÜÇ','áéíóúàèìòùãõâêîôôäëïöüç') 
from Client.
```

This should return 'DENES'.

I am using Windows and DB2 v9.7.0.1

How to do this using OpenJPA 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a [native query](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/1.0.x/manual/manual.html#jpa_overview_sqlquery).